# Image shown in imageView loses aspect ratio and becomes squished when saved to camera roll

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm making an image app that can put simple frames over images loaded into the imageView and save them as a new image for practice, because I'm very new to swift and trying to learn. These screenshots show the frame hidden because the problem is with the image loaded behind the frame.

My rep isn't high enough to post images but the specific issue is: Image shown in imageView loses aspect ratio and becomes squished widthwise when saved to camera roll.

I have my imageView's constraints set to maintain a specific aspect ratio with any sized device so it grows and shrinks accordingly. I also have it's content mode set to aspect fill via IB.

The aspect fill works exactly how I'd expect until I save the image. When I hit save the image inside the image view instantly squishes width wise and loses its aspect ratio.

I import the image to the imageView with this:

```
 func importPicture() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

    dismiss(animated: true)

    currentImage = image
    unchangedImage = image

    self.imageView.image = currentImage

}
```

Then I draw:

```
func drawImagesAndText() {

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

    img = renderer.image { ctx in


     let bgImage = currentImage
        bgImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

        let frame = UIImage(named: "5x4frame")
        frame?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))
    }
    imageView.image = img
}
```

This was the only way I could think to do it to allow the image to be drawn while also having the image view dynamic.

this is the save function I'm using, I have this function tied to a "save button's" outlet from IB.

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
```

thanks for any and all advice

Comment: update screenshot also

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari OP said they don't have the rep to post images in the question.

Comment: Non handling of Aspect ratio of Image result such issue , think of it , may fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Would I handle the aspect ratio in the draw function?